# Validation Error in mongoose and node.js (ERROR IS BELOW)

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am getting this error

this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);

The full error message will be below the codes

index.js file

```
//Requiring Dependencies
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const path = require('path');

const session = require('express-session');

const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local')

//Require Models
const Product = require('./models/product');
const User = require('./models/user');

//To run and parse EJS
const engine = require('ejs-mate');

//Connecting to DB server
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ecom', {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
})
    .then(() => {
        console.log('DATABASE CONNECTED')
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log('SOMETHING WENT WRONG WITH MONGO')
        console.log(err)
    })

    //Using EJS-Mate
    app.engine('ejs' , engine);
    app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
    app.set('views' , path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

    const sessionConfig = {
        secret: 'secrethere',
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: true,
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
            expires: Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
        }
    }
    app.use(session(sessionConfig))

    //Using Passport
    app.use(passport.initialize())
    //So user does not have to login after every single request
    app.use(passport.session())
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()))

    
    //How to store a user in the session
    passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());

    //How to get user out of that session
    passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


    app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

    //For use of files like js and css in public directory
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')))

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './images')))

   


    app.get('/' , (req , res) => {

    })

    app.get('/home' , (req , res) => {
        res.render('pages/homepage')
    })

    app.get('/login' , (req , res) => {
        res.render('pages/loginPage')
    })

    app.get('/signup' ,(req , res) => {
        res.render('pages/signup')
    })

    //Creating a new user
    app.post('/signup' , async(req , res) => {
        const {username , email, password, country, city, zipcode, street} = req.body
        const user =  new User({
            username,
            email,
            country,
            city,
            zipcode,
            street
        })
      const registeredUser = await User.register(user, password);
      console.log(registeredUser)
    })


    //Port
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('LISTENING ON PORT 3000')
})
```

This is the user model file

```
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

const userSchema = new Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        country: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        city:{
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        street: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        zipcode: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    shipping_address: {
        country: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        street: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        zipcode: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    }
});
//Using Paspport Plugin
userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User' , userSchema);
```

This is the full error

> C:\Users\hadiz\Desktop\Business\portfolioprojects\ecommerce\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2907
> this.$__.validationError = new ValidationError(this);
> ^
>
> ValidationError: User validation failed: shipping_address.zipcode:
> Path `shipping_address.zipcode` is required., shipping_address.street:
> Path `shipping_address.street` is required., shipping_address.country:
> Path `shipping_address.country` is required., address.zipcode: Path
> `address.zipcode` is required., address.street: Path `address.street`
> is required., address.city: Path `address.city` is required.,
> address.country: Path `address.country` is required.
> at model.Document.invalidate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should refer to the nested properties of the `address` and `shipping_address` objects in your schema when registering a new user:

```
app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
  const { username, email, password, country, city, zipcode, street } =
    req.body;
  const user = new User({
    username,
    email,
    address: { country, city, zipcode, street },
    shipping_address: { country, city, zipcode },
  });
  const registeredUser = await User.register(user, password);
  console.log(registeredUser);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the shipping address is a nested object in the schema and is required.

change to

`const user=newUser({`

`username,email,`

`shipping_address:{zipcode,street,country},`

`address:{city,zipcode,street,country}`

`})`